# Table does not use entire space of page!

Tags: tables, statistics

My table cannot fit on one page.
If I could only split the table up over two pages or maybe make it start in the very top of the page instead of beginning the table in like the middle of the page then I could fix my problem.

My code is here:

```
\begin{table}[p]
\centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Pooled OLS and Fixed effects estimation on the initial model (eq. 1)}
     \begin{tabular}{llllll}
        \toprule
       \(Dependent variable: \Delta H_{it}\)  & \( Initial\ POLS \) & \( Initial\ FE \) & \ \\
        \midrule
            \\
$Male$ & -.00154*** &  & &  &  \\
       & (.00033) &&&& \\
$Age$ & .00195*** & .00094 &  &  &  \\
& (.00069) & (.00113) &&& \\
$Age^{2}$ & -.00002*** & -.00002*** &  &  &  \\
& (.00000) & (.00000) &&& \\
$Black$ & .00180*** &  &  & &  \\
& (.00052) &&&& \\
$Hispanic$ & .00095 &  &  & &  \\
& (.00068) &&&& \\
$Married/partner$ & -.00069*** & -.00357*** &  &  &  \\
& (.00043) & (.00127) &&& \\
$log(assets)$ & .00055*** & .00031* & 0.362 & 0 & 1 \\
& (.00008) &(.00017) &&& \\
$log(debt)$ & -.00016*** & -.00006 & 0.245 & 0 & 1 \\
& (.00005) & (.00008)&&& \\
$Some highschool$ & .00146** & &  &  &  \\
& (.00063) &&&& \\
$Highschool (GED)$ & .00120** &  &  & &  \\
& (.00057) &&&& \\
$AA$ & .00122 &  &  &  &  \\
& (.00084) &&&& \\
$Bachelor degree$ & .00228*** &  &  & &  \\
& (.00067) &&&& \\
$Graduate degree$ & .00287*** &  &  &  & \\
& (.00067) &&&& \\
$RS_{it}$* & -.00884*** & -.00717*** &  &  &  \\
& (.00101) & (.00112) &&& \\
$RL_{it}$ & -.00014 & .00135 &  &  &  \\
& (.00051) & (.00089) &&& \\
$Constant$ & -.07498*** & -.00814 &  & &  \\
& (.02142) & (.04949) &&& \\
\\
$time$ & &  &  &  &  \\
3 & .00209* & .00369* &  &  &  \\
& (.00051) & (.00193) &&& \\
4 & -.00717 & -.00398 &  &  &  \\
& (.00104) & (.00323) &&& \\
5 & .004299*** & .00950** &  &  &  \\
& (.00097) & (.00468) &&& \\
6 & -.00268*** & .00476 &  & &  \\
& (.00100) & (.00636) &&& \\
7 & -.00348*** & .00602 &  & & \\
& (.00104) & (.00787) &&& \\
8 & -.00000 & .01158 &  &  &  \\
& (.00091) & (.00949) &&& \\
9 & -.00327*** & .01006 &  &  &  \\
& (.00095) & (.01099) &&& \\
10 & -.00154 & .01719 &  &  &  \\
& (.00100) & (.01278) &&& \\

              \end{tabular}
           \begin{tablenotes}
        \small
      \item Notes:
      \item *: dummy variable estimates refer to sample                     proportions rather than averages
      \item A: Originally 1 - excellent, 2 - very good, 3 - good, 4 - fair, 5 - poor. Probit estimations did not work so I rescaled to 0 - poor, 0.25 - fair, 0.5 - good, 0.75 - very good, 1 - excellent
      \item B: See section 3.2
   \end{tablenotes}
 \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

Comment: If you want a table to be on top of a page, use option `t` for `table` environment

Comment: I tried chahing the "p" to a "t" in "\begin{table}[t]" but it doesnt work. The table still start way too far down.. can I move it up without changing margins??

Comment: Of course, because your table is so big that every floating options produces the same bad result. Consider using something like `longtable` or manually split your table to two independent tables and use `t` for each of those tables.

Comment: how would one use `longtable` in this scenario? I already tried replacing "begin{table}" with "begin{longtable" and adding in preamble

Comment: That is just my suggestion. I have no experiences with `longtable` honestly. Maybe you should wait for some TeXperts out there.